# Passing value from jquery to php variable in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know similar questions to this have been asked before but I don't see an answer that suits my question. I have a div that triggers a jquery script which stores an id. I can get the id into a variable in the jquery but I want to then assign that id to a PHP variable that exists on the same page.

So far this is what I've got. Here is my div that exists in `index.php`:

```
echo '<div id="'.$unit_id.'" class="dropdown unit '.$unit_size.' unit-'.$unit_number.' '.$unit_status.' data-unit-id-'.$unit_id.'">';
```

And here is my jquery that I call in from `functions.php`:

```
<script>
    $('.unit.available').click(function(){
        var unit_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {id: unit_id}, //Pass the id
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to pass the `unit_id` into a variable on `index.php` called `$getID` but I can't seem to find a way of getting in there. I've tried using post but there really isn't a form being submitted. It's just a dive being clicked on.

Comment: You need to debug this one step at a time. If the click handler is not called then obviously the Ajax call won't happen, so check the click handler first and once you know that is working check the Ajax code. (`$('.unit.available').click(...)` will only put a click handler on elements that have both the `unit` and `available` classes *at the time that script runs*. So given that your element doesn't initially have the `available` class it won't have a click handler.)

Comment: Use success callback of AJAX

Comment: There is a small mistake. you are not written `php` inside `php` tag, move your code inside ta

Comment: «I want to then assign that id to a PHP variable that exists on the same page.» «...on the same page»... This is causing the confusion. You should read more on [What is Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The div tag is actually inside an echo

Comment: @SunilPachlangia doing a success callback outputs the id so the script is working

Comment: if it helps, what I'm trying to accomplish you can see on this page. https://selfstorageeasthaven.com/booking.php. See how the info up top changes when you click on one of the units? That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your `id` in your `<div>` and set it to fetch the variable sent by jQuery. Other than that, your jQuery script looks fine.

Here's how I would do it:

```
# Fetch the variable if it's set.
<?php $unit_id = (isset($_POST["id"])) ? $_POST["id"] : null; ?>

# Echo it as the id of the div.
<div id = "<?= $unit_id; ?>" class = "dropdown unit"></div>
```

### EDIT:

The PHP code above is equal to:

```
# Fetch the variable if it's set.
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["id"])):
        $unit_id = $_POST["id"];
    else:
        $unit_id = null;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: is `<?php $unit_id = (isset($_POST["id"])) ? $_POST["id"] : null; ?>` supposed to grab the id if it is set in jquery?

Comment: Yes. It will check if the id has successfully been passed to PHP and if it has it will assign it to the variable `$unit_id`. Check out my edit for an explanation of the code.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Assign id to div id attribute like this, Use:

```
<div id="<?php echo $unit_id; ?>" class="dropdown unit"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this hope it will work

```
<div id="<?php echo $unit_id;?>" class="dropdown unit"></div>


<script>
    $('.unit.available').click(function(){
        var unit_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            'id='+unit_id, //Pass the id
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `type: 'post', 'id='+unit_id, //Pass the id` i don't understand why you are passing id like this.

Comment: It will work. just another way to pass data. you say why not pass id this way?

Comment: Never do that, follow standards. as ajax have, or else you will miss features. and don`t advice this to others

Comment: I am sure it will not miss any features provided by ajax. And don't generate any kind of problems

Answer (score -1):

What you mean by this '$unit_id' in div ID. Just put the code in PHP Tag, while working with PHP in HTML pages use the code inside PHP tags.

Availale PHP tags : `<?php echo $unit_id ?>` (or) `<?=$unit_id ?>` (short tag).

Change your div with  :

```
<div id="<?=$unit_id ?>" class="dropdown unit"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="<?php echo $unit_id ?>" class="dropdown unit"></div>
```

Then your script will be work

```
<script>
    $('.unit.available').click(function(){
        var unit_id = $(this).attr('id');
       // to check whether value passing or not 
       console.log(unit_id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {id: unit_id}, //Pass the id
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are Right @Fareed.

Comment: unfortunately the problem isn't that my div doesn't have the right tags. The code for the div is actually inside an `echo`. I'll edit my question to reflect this. Your script works just like mine but I want to know how to get the `unit_id` into a php variable that I can echo onto `index.php`.